# How to count word match in content mysql match against?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use match against to find article, and count how many keyword match this article. For example, if my article is 'today's weather is very nice', and my keywords are 'today nice', so the count should be 2, how can I do it. When i use code below, it count how many article match, but not how many keyword match in an article.

```html
<?php
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE MATCH (article) AGAINST ('today nice');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below examples.

**1.** Get count which contains the words 'today' and 'nice'

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE MATCH(article) AGAINST('+today +nice' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

**2.** Get count which contains the words 'today' but rank rows higher if they also contain 'nice'

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE MATCH(article) AGAINST('+today nice' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

**3.** Get count which contains the words 'today' or 'nice'

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE MATCH(article) AGAINST('today nice' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

For more detail you can ride [MYSQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Hope this help you well!

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i want to count how many words match in one row, your examples are counting how many row match.

Comment: Did you mean "Number Of Words In A Field For Each Row"?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'the'` with the substring value you are trying to count.  Replace `` `text` `` with your column name.

```
SELECT (LENGTH(`text`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`text`, 'the', ''))) / LENGTH('the') AS total 
FROM someTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example that may helps:

```
mysql> select `id`, `url`, LENGTH(`url`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`url`, '/', '')) as `number` from `url`;
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
| id | url                           | number |
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | http://www.google.com         |      2 |
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
```